# Google map marker with Fresco for android

Tags: android, google-maps, fresco

I try to display images from internet in Google map marker using `Fresco` (following [this guide](http://frescolib.org/docs/writing-custom-views.html)), but only a placeholder is displayed.

In callback marker is redrawing. `Fresco's DraweeView` is working fine with my url.

My marker:

```
public class MarkerHolder {
    private final String TAG = MarkerHolder.class.getSimpleName();

    private DraweeHolder mDraweeHolder;
    private Handler mUiHandler;

    public MarkerHolder() {
        mUiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    public void create(Context context, Uri uri, Drawable placeHolderDrawable, Callback<Drawable> drawCallback) {

        mDraweeHolder = DraweeHolder.create(new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(context.getResources())
                .setPlaceholderImage(placeHolderDrawable)
                .build(), context);

        mDraweeHolder.setController(Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setUri(uri)
                .setOldController(mDraweeHolder.getController())
                .build());

        mDraweeHolder.getTopLevelDrawable().setCallback(new Drawable.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void invalidateDrawable(@NonNull Drawable who) {
                mDraweeHolder.onDraw();
                drawCallback.onAction(who);
            }

            @Override
            public void scheduleDrawable(@NonNull Drawable who, @NonNull Runnable what, long when) {
                mUiHandler.postAtTime(what, who, when);
            }

            @Override
            public void unscheduleDrawable(@NonNull Drawable who, @NonNull Runnable what) {
                mUiHandler.removeCallbacks(what, who);
            }
        });
        mDraweeHolder.onAttach();
        mDraweeHolder.onDraw();
        drawCallback.onAction(mDraweeHolder.getTopLevelDrawable());
    }

    public void destroy() {
        mDraweeHolder.onDetach();
        mDraweeHolder.getTopLevelDrawable().setCallback(null);
    }
    public interface Callback<T> {
        public void onAction(T t);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Did tou solve this?

Comment: @Nux No, I decided to use Glide